# Making a table for critical points values for a function of two variables

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I like to see a table, what type of points ( Maximum,Sadle, Minimum) , Point and Value of Function shows.

Given a function f:

`f = -3*x^2 + x^4 + 3*y + (x*y)/2 - 2*y^3`

`Plot3D[-3*x^2 + x^4 + 3*y + (x*y)/2 - 2*y^3, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]`

- find the critical points

For critical points we do need **first order** partial derivatives for x and y.
Both must be zero: can be done with a gradient or with partiele derivative for x and y
`crPts = NSolve[Grad[f, {x, y}] == {0, 0}, {x, y}]`

`crtPts2 = NSolve[{D[f, x] == 0 && D[f, y] == 0}, {x, y}]`

Note notation :  D[f, x] =  $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$

- Find the **second order** partial derivatives( using this for form  A1*C1-B1^2) for classifying critical points.

`A1 = D[f, x, x]`

`B1 = D[f, x, y]`

`C1=D[f, {y, 2}]`

- In a loop, using the quadratic form  A1*C1-B1^2, examine each of the 6 critical points:

For k from 1 to  6 do :
(there are 6 points, manual counted)

Using *crtPts2* : getting a subscript for k

Constructing this loop with some if statements in it, that is the task ?

Output : a table with heading: Type_of_Point, Point,  Value_of_Functions

Type_of_Point: Maximum, Saddle, Minimum

Points (critical) : x,y values

Value_of_Function : z-value

Comment: 1) what have you tried to solve the problem so far? 2) finding a functions critical points is a pretty common problem that has been discussed before on this site. See for instance some do the "Related" questions in the panel on the right on this page.

Comment: Indeed finding critical points is not the problem.
I want to do the calculation of the critical points with a do loop and present it in a table that is what this question is about.
I have studied the Do loop, but an if statement with the table construction is still unknown to me 
Actually you have to do this in steps.

Comment: Typically working in explicit loops is not the most effective way to write Mathematica code. If you have the points already, then please include the code that gave you those points. Generate them in a list (e.g. using Table or Map) and then format them afterwards. The question at the moment sounds like the problem is getting the points, but you seem to say that the problem if formatting them in a table, so clarifications are needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seldom need Do loops in MMA. It is better to work with all data at once. In your case:

Critical points:

```
cps = Solve[Grad[f, {x, y}] == {0, 0}, {x, y}] // N
```

[image]

To determine the type of points we need the second derivatives matrix, the so called Hessian. The eigenvalues of the Hessian determine the type. If they are both positive, it is a maximum, negative, it is a minimum and if they differ it is a saddle;

```
hes = D[f, {{x, y}, 2}] /. cps;
eig= Eigenvalues /@ hes
```

[image]

With this we create a function that returns the type:

```
type = Switch[Sign[ #], {1, 1}, "Min", {-1, -1}, 
    "Max", {-1, 1} | {1, -1}, "Saddle"] &;
```

No we have all the information to create a list or a plot:

```
TableForm[Table[{type[eig[[i]]], {x, y} /. cps[[i]], f /. cps[[i]]}, {i,6}], TableHeadings -> {None, {"Type", "Point", "Function Value"}}]
```

[image]

```
Show[Plot3D[f, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -1, 1}]
 , Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.03], Point[{x, y, f} /. cps], 
   MapThread[Text[type[#1], {x, y, 3 + f} /. #2] &, {eig, cps}]}]
 ]
```

[image: s]

Comment: Thanks. doing this with a determinant : The Hessian,  its faster then checking all points one by one : as seen in the in the student's introduction to Mathematica.
This calculation of stationary points I also have here also using Maple and there a do loop and if statements were used.
In principle I should be able to just translate it to MMA , but it didn't work out very well yet.
By the way, I like working with MMA better than Maple with the simpler description of the commands.    
One thing i like is also a  table heading : Type_of_point,Point,Value_of_function

Comment: I added table headings

Comment: Thanks again, It's clearer now what the table stands for.

Comment: Is it also possible to add a gradientplot to the bottom of the 3D box from Plot3D?

Comment: VectorPlot[Grad[f, {x, y}], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -1, 1}]

Comment: Unfortunately, the plot is still not right.
Complex numbers appear in the table for the function values for saddle points ?

Comment: Ok, solved the function input was not correct
Only getting a gradientplot on bottom of box plot is troublesome

Comment: ??? does VectorPlot as shown above not work?

Comment: Its a empty plot .., but there is also a GradientFieldPlot command

Comment: Ok, this works : `VectorPlot[{-6*x + 4*x^3 + y/2, 3 + x/2 - 6*y^2}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -1, 1}]`

Comment: Now only left over , adding the `VectorPlot` to this plot ? : `Show[Plot3D[f, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -1, 1}], 
  Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.03], Point[{x, y, f} /. cps], 
    MapThread[Text[type[#1], {x, y, 3 + f} /. #2] & , {eig, cps}]}]]`

Comment: Does "Column" or "Row" do what you want? "Inset" is a bit tricky because you have a 3D and a 2D graphics.

Comment: That's also where I was afraid it wouldn't work for combining a 2 D plot into a 3D plot. 
Maybe with `GradientFieldPlot3D` for z= 0 ?

Comment: Column or Row and Inset .. don't know yet their meaning ?

Comment: Look it up in the help.

Comment: What would happen with this code if the Hessian is zero?

Comment: @Moo , Assume that the Hessian is zero, then further investigation is required to determine any local maxima and/or minima

Comment: Yes, my point is should the code display that case as undetermined, and print a message that further investigation is/are required for that point(s), so this solution generalizes.

Comment: The Hessian is the quadratic part of an Taylor expansion. That the Hessian is zero is a bit academic, it happens seldom. But in this case you need the cubic terms. And if these are zero, you need the quartic terms...

Comment: Getting a gradientplot together with this surface in one plot, seems to be mission impossible?

Comment: You can do this, but because one is a 3D and the other a 2D graphics, it is not simple and you should get more acquainted with MMA before tackle complicated tasks

Comment: Indeed, that is now getting too complicated for me to figure out. In Maple I had a surface together with a gradient plot which gave more insight.
Maple is more focused on education than MMA.

Comment: @janhardo  "Getting a gradientplot together with this surface in one plot" I think you mean `SliceVectorPlot3D`?: `f = -3*x^2 + x^4 + 3*y + (x*y)/2 - 2*y^3;
Show[Plot3D[f, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -1, 1}], 
 SliceVectorPlot3D[D[f, {{x, y, z}}] // Evaluate, 
   z == -5, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -11, 1}, VectorPoints -> 20, 
   VectorMarkers -> "Arrow"] /. Arrow[a_] :> {Arrowheads[0.005], Arrow[a]}, 
 PlotRange -> {-6, 6}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]` (I add the rule `/. Arrow[a_] :> {Arrowheads[0.005], Arrow[a]}` because the default scaling of arrow is strange, which looks like a bug to me. )

Comment: @ xzczd, thanks  Yes, that is exactly what I was looking for.
The gradient ground plane shows the stationary points of the surface above it